# Simulate a sticky fluid in Blender

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to simulate a fluid that gives me a fresh paint effect, once it is on the object the liquid drips and lets the object dirty (with some drops)
Actually, the "best" result i got is setting high viscosity, low speed for the fluid and no slip for the obstacle, but in any case the fluid does not stick to the object.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look into [Blender Molecular Addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKiFjv3LMWo)

Comment: The Flip Fluid addon maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible with fluid simulation itself. The fluid sim does not do sticking itself to a surface as a feature (sometimes you get it as a bug).

Workarounds i can think of:

1. Stop the fluid sim at the point where it should stick and apply the modifier making the mesh solid.
2. Use dynamic paint modifier with the fluid sim mesh as a brush. Use the resulting paint output with a bump map to give it some texture.